# Ember: overriding property from imported mixin?

Tags: ember.js, mixins

I have a simple mixin that uses a property to perform an action. I'm trying to model inheritance so that I can **override** this property in the Component that uses the mixin.

For the same benefit of overriding in any OO language.

I appreciate using `extend` may be preferable for modelling inheritance but I wonder if this is possible with a mixin.

---

I have tried using `this.get('')` to retrieve a property from my component that doesn't exist in the mixin. The idea being I can check if the programmer wants to specify the element to focus. If not, use a default. This returns nothing even when the property is defined on the implementing component.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Mixin from '@ember/object/mixin';

export default Mixin.create({
  didRender() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    $(this.get('elementToFocus') ? this.get('elementToFocus') : 'h1').focus();
  }
});
```

I have also tried using a property on the mixin and then duplicating the property in the component. This breaks everything and gives me random errors.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Mixin from '@ember/object/mixin';

export default Mixin.create({
  elementToFocus: 'h1',
  didRender() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    $(this.get('elementToFocus')).focus();
});
```

If you can see what I'm trying to achieve, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is hard to understand what do you want to achieve. And hard to give any suggestions without code of component

Comment: Well simply put I want the best way to make a property accessed, somehow, inside the mixin, dynamic depending on the whim of the component implementing it. The code from the component would just be importing the mixin, for the most part.  Don't think it adds nything

Comment: Code inside mixin has access to property of component extending it. See [this line](https://github.com/GendelfLugansk/jira-stats/blob/master/app/components/reports/chart-mixin.js#L82) (in mixin I access `fetch` property) and [this](https://github.com/GendelfLugansk/jira-stats/blob/master/app/components/reports/max-work-ratio-by-label.js#L12) (in component I define `fetch`).

Comment: You're code looks good, this should work. Can you provide a non working twiddle? How do you use the mixin?

Comment: This works in a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e31a940d54e80cc0fc1422821376a56f?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) for latest Chrome and Firefox. In an older Firefox ESR 52 it did NOT work (the focus()). Maybe you're using such an older browser?

Comment: @GennadyDogaev Thanks for those examples man. Strange thing is I tried that and  it didn't work for me, debugger would show null/undefined. Luckily resolved now, not sure, must have been some dependency I was using affecting the scope of things like `this.`? Anyway thanks

Comment: @Enno Thanks for that Twiddle! I didn't get round to making one myself because I was occupied on the weekend :)    strangely that had been one of the approaches I tried but as I say `this.get('')` kept returned undefined !!  

Resolved now by my friend, not sure what was happening, might have been a dependancy or something affecting me env...I'm guessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your comments. They seem to confirm my suspicions that much of what I was trying / had tried SHOULD have worked.

My friend got it to work using `const focusElement = document.querySelector(this.elementToFocus);`

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong.